# Issue with css and bootstrap grids

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm kind of new at bootstrap, and I'm trying to practice this, I have a web is very simple I know, but I'm having troubles whith this, because The grid like It doesn't center the this, I already put the css, I don't know If you can tell me what it's going on, Be pacient with me I'm learning :( 
If you be my guide I'll be so grateful

```
<html>


<head>
    <meta charset="utf8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Mountain at my Gates</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>




<body>
<header class="main_menu_sec navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
            <div class="lft_hd">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""/></a>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
            <div class="rgt_hd">
            <div class="main_menu">
                <nav id="nav_menu">
                    <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div id="navbar">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a></li>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#countsec">we</a></li>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a></li>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                </nav>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</header>

<section id="slider_section">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="slider">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  </ol>


                  <!--- wrapper -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="wrap_caption">
                                 <div class="caption_carousel">
                                    <h1>I see a Mountain at my gates </h1>
                                    <p>I see more and more each day</p>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                        <div class="wrap_caption">
                          <div class="caption_carousel">
                            <h1>What I give, it takes away</h1>
                            <p>Whether I go or when I stay</p>
                          </div>                        
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="wrap_caption">
                          <div class="caption_carousel">
                            <h1>I see a mountain in my way</h1>
                            <p>It's looming larger by the day</p>
                          </div>                        
                        </div>
                    </div>  


        </div>

        <a class="left left_crousel_btn" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right right_crousel_btn" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>


    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>


<section id="about">
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12 ">
                <div class="title_sec">
                    <h1>ABOUT</h1>
                    <h2>Mountain at my gates</h2>
                </div>          
            </div>      
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12 ">
                <div class="abt">
                    <p>I see it more and more each day What I give, it takes away Whether I go or when I stay </p>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="countsec">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                    <div class="count">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    <h2 class="counter">1994</h2>
                    <h4>I see a Mountain at my gates</h4>   
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="count">
                        <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
                        <h2 class="counter">21</h2>
                        <h4>I see it more and more each day</h4>    
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="count">
                        <i class="fa fa-ticket"></i>
                        <h2 class="counter">02</h2>
                        <h4>It takes away </h4> 
                    </div>
                </div>  

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="count">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                        <h2 class="counter">05</h2>
                        <h4>My mountain</h4>    
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>  
        </div>      

</section>

<section id="serv">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12 ">
                <div class="title_sec">
                    <h1>Mountain at my gates</h1>
                    <h2>I see it more and more each day</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="service">                       
                    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                    <h2>web Development</h2>
                    <div class="service_hoverly">
                        <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                        <h2>web Development</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ab odio quas  , voluptate aspernatur!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="service">                       
                    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
                    <h2>E-mail marketing</h2>
                    <div class="service_hoverly">
                        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
                        <h2>E-mail marketing</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ab odio quas  , voluptate aspernatur!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="service">                       
                    <i class="fa fa-wordpress"></i>
                    <h2>WordPress</h2>
                    <div class="service_hoverly">
                        <i class="fa fa-wordpress"></i>
                        <h2>WordPress</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ab odio quas  , voluptate aspernatur!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  


            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="service">                       
                    <i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>
                    <h2>Graphic Design</h2>
                    <div class="service_hoverly">
                        <i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>
                        <h2>Graphic Design</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ab odio quas  , voluptate aspernatur!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="team">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12 ">
                <div class="title_sec">
                    <h1>Team</h1>
                    <h2>Mountain</h2>
                </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12">
                <div class="all_team">

                    <div class="sngl_team">                     
                        <img src="http://wedesignthemes.com/themes/dt-mountcool/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/img-1.png" alt=""/>  
                        <h3> Jamie Catllahan <span>Designer</span></h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecttur adipisicing elit. Laudant</p>                     
                </div>                  
                    <div class="sngl_team">                     
                        <img src="http://wedesignthemes.com/themes/dt-mountcool/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/img-2.png" alt=""/>  
                        <h3>Lisa Kudrow <span> Manager </span></h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecttur adipisicing elit. Laudant</p>                     
                    </div>              
                    <div class="sngl_team">                     
                        <img src="http://wedesignthemes.com/themes/dt-mountcool/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/img-3.png" alt=""/>  
                        <h3> John Clarance <span>   Senior Manager   </span></h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecttur adipisicing elit. Laudant</p>                     
                    </div>              

        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/appear.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/showHide.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        $('.counter').counterUp({
            delay: 10,
            time: 1000
        });
    });
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

and my css

```
body {

background : #fff;
}

body p {
color : #666666;
font-family : "Lato", sans-serif;
font-size : 14px;
letter-spacing : 1px;
}
body h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
color : #141414;
font-family : "Lato", sans-serif;
font-size : 18px;
text-transform : capitalize;
font-weight : 800;
text-transform : uppercase;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration : none;
}
.navbar {
padding : 10px 0;
transition : background 0.5s ease-in-out, padding 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#nav_menu ul {
float : right;
list-style : none outside none;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
position : relative;
}
#nav_menu ul a {
color : #ffffff;
display : block;
font-family : lato;
font-size : 14px;
font-weight : bold;
line-height : 32px;
padding : 25px 14px;
text-decoration : none;
text-transform : capitalize;
transition : all 0.4s 0s ease;
}
#nav_menu ul li {
float : left;
padding : 0;
position : relative;
}
#nav_menu ul li a:hover {
transition : all 0.4s 0s ease;
background : #0078BF;
}
#nav_menu ul ul {
background : none 0 0 repeat scroll #0078bf;
display : none;
left : 0;
padding : 0;
position : absolute;
top : 100%;
z-index : 9999;
padding : 10px;
}
#nav_menu ul ul li {
float : none;
width : 200px;
}
#nav_menu ul ul a {
line-height : 120%;
padding : 10px 29px;
}
#nav_menu ul ul li a:hover {
transition : all 0.4s 0s ease;
background : #333333;
}
#nav_menu ul ul ul {
top : 0;
left : 100%;
}
#nav_menu ul li:hover > ul {
display : block;
}
#nav_menu ul li a i {
margin-left : 6px;
}

.title_sec {
margin : 0 auto;
padding : 0 0 25px 0;
text-align : center;
}
.title_sec h2 {
color : #606060;
font-size : 12px;
text-transform : uppercase;
letter-spacing : 1px;
}



.wrap_caption {
padding : 190px 0;
}
.slider {
display : block;
text-align : center;
vertical-align : middle;
width : 100%;
}
#slider_sec {
background-image : url(".../img/fnd.jpg");
background-position : center center;
background-repeat : no-repeat;
background-size : 100% 100%;
height : 100%;
width : 100%;
}
.left_crousel_btn, .right_crousel_btn {
color : #fff;
height : 20px;
position : absolute;
text-align : center;
top : 50%;
width : 20px;
font-size : 25px;
font-weight : normal;
}
.caption_carousel h1 {
font-family : lato;
font-size : 60px;
text-transform : capitalize;
color : #fff;
}
.caption_carousel p {
font-family : lato;
font-size : 14px;
color : #f6f6f6;
border-top : 1px solid #fff;
border-bottom : 1px solid #fff;
display : inline;
line-height : 35px;
padding : 8px;
}
.caption_carousel {
display : table-cell;
text-align : center;
vertical-align : middle;
height : 100%;
width : 100%;
margin : 0 auto;
display : block;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
background-color : #363636;
border : none medium;
border-radius : 5px;
cursor : pointer;
display : inline-block;
height : 6px;
text-indent : 0;
width : 25px;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
width : 25px;
height : 7px;
background-color : #00AFF0;
}

.wrap_caption {
padding : 190px 0;
}


#about {
padding : 70px 0;
}

#countsec {
background : none 0 0 repeat scroll #f0f0f0;
padding : 90px 0;
}
.count h2 {
color : #515050;
font-size : 48px;
}
.count h4 {
font-size : 18px;
color : #515050;
text-transform : uppercase;
font-weight : 300;
}
.count {
text-align : center;
}
.count i {
color : #515050;
float : left;
font-size : 35px;
margin-top : 10px;
}
#pr_sec {
padding : 70px 0;
}

#pr_sec {
padding : 70px 0;
}
.serv {

transition: all 1s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;border :1px solid #eeeeee;
cursor : pointer;
text-align : center;
padding : 61px 0;

}
.service:hover .service_hoverly {
display : block;
}
.service > h2 {
color : #515050;
font-size : 14px;
font-weight : 400;
text-transform : uppercase;
}
.service_hoverly h2 {
color : #515050;
font-size : 14px;
font-weight : 400;
text-transform : uppercase;
margin : 0;
padding-bottom : 30px;
}
.service i {
font-size : 50px;
color : #03B0F0;
position : relative;
}
.service_hoverly {

transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;border :1px solid #03B0F0;
display : none;
padding : 25px 5px;
position : absolute;
top : 0;
background : #fff;
}
.service_hoverly i {
background : none 0 0 repeat scroll #fff;
font-size : 50px;
position : relative;
top : -50px;
}

#team {
padding : 70px 0;
}
.sngl_team h3 {
font-size : 14px;
text-transform : uppercase;
color : #333333;
}
.sngl_team {
text-align : center;
width : 100%;
}
.owl-item .sngl_team img {
margin : 0 auto;
text-align : center;
width : 130px;
}
.sngl_team span {
color : #00aff0;
font-family : lato;
font-size : 13px;
margin-left : 10px;
text-transform : uppercase;
}
.all_team .owl-controls .owl-prev i {
color : #3399ff;
font-size : 30px;
position : absolute;
top : 46%;
left : 0;
}
.all_team .owl-controls .owl-next i {
position : absolute;
top : 46%;
font-size : 30px;
color : #3399FF;
right : 0%;
}
.all_team .owl-controls .owl-dot {
background-color : #363636;
border : none medium;
border-radius : 5px;
cursor : pointer;
display : inline-block;
height : 6px;
text-indent : 0;
width : 25px;
margin-right : 5px;
}
.all_team .owl-controls .owl-dot.active {
background-color : #03B0F0;
}
.all_team .owl-controls {
display : inline-block;
width : 100%;
text-align : center;
}
```

Comment: Please put that into a snippet (7th button in the editor toolbar) so it is easier to see what is going on.

Comment: Try using a Bootply and you will get quicker assistance. Set up your question so the person answering can use your code in a snipit made just for that purpose. Here is a link to [Bootply - LINK](https://www.bootply.com/new). Add your HTML, JS and CSS to the snipit there and then post a link to it. Or as the 'schrej' indicated use the code snipit built into the tool bar here in SO. Best of luck.

Comment: I'd also try to post a much smaller amount of code if I were you, most people don't have time to go through 600 lines of HTML/CSS. 
Here is something you might want to consider when you ask a question: The code examples should be [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Two places are not centered, I added a class and add it to the **parent of the element you want to center**:

```
.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Now the `about` text and the 4 grid below are centered.

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}

body p {
  color: #666666;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

body h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #141414;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out, padding 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#nav_menu ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#nav_menu ul a {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: lato;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 25px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: all 0.4s 0s ease;
}

#nav_menu ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#nav_menu ul li a:hover {
  transition: all 0.4s 0s ease;
  background: #0078BF;
}

#nav_menu ul ul {
  background: none 0 0 repeat scroll #0078bf;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 10px;
}

#nav_menu ul ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 200px;
}

#nav_menu ul ul a {
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px 29px;
}

#nav_menu ul ul li a:hover {
  transition: all 0.4s 0s ease;
  background: #333333;
}

#nav_menu ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

#nav_menu ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#nav_menu ul li a i {
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.title_sec {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.title_sec h2 {
  color: #606060;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.wrap_caption {
  padding: 190px 0;
}

.slider {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

#slider_sec {
  background-image: url(".../img/fnd.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.left_crousel_btn,
.right_crousel_btn {
  color: #fff;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.caption_carousel h1 {
  font-family: lato;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #fff;
}

.caption_carousel p {
  font-family: lato;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #f6f6f6;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  display: inline;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.caption_carousel {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  background-color: #363636;
  border: none medium;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 6px;
  text-indent: 0;
  width: 25px;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  width: 25px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #00AFF0;
}

.wrap_caption {
  padding: 190px 0;
}

#about {
  padding: 70px 0;
}

#countsec {
  background: none 0 0 repeat scroll #f0f0f0;
  padding: 90px 0;
}

.count h2 {
  color: #515050;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.count h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #515050;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.count {
  text-align: center;
}

.count i {
  color: #515050;
  float: left;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#pr_sec {
  padding: 70px 0;
}

#pr_sec {
  padding: 70px 0;
}

.serv {
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 61px 0;
}

.service:hover .service_hoverly {
  display: block;
}

.service>h2 {
  color: #515050;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.service_hoverly h2 {
  color: #515050;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.service i {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #03B0F0;
  position: relative;
}

.service_hoverly {
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  border: 1px solid #03B0F0;
  display: none;
  padding: 25px 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.service_hoverly i {
  background: none 0 0 repeat scroll #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}

#team {
  padding: 70px 0;
}

.sngl_team h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333333;
}

.sngl_team {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.owl-item .sngl_team img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 130px;
}

.sngl_team span {
  color: #00aff0;
  font-family: lato;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.all_team .owl-controls .owl-prev i {
  color: #3399ff;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 46%;
  left: 0;
}

.all_team .owl-controls .owl-next i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 46%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #3399FF;
  right: 0%;
}

.all_team .owl-controls .owl-dot {
  background-color: #363636;
  border: none medium;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 6px;
  text-indent: 0;
  width: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.all_team .owl-controls .owl-dot.active {
  background-color: #03B0F0;
}

.all_team .owl-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<head>
  <meta charset="utf8" />
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Mountain at my Gates</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>




<body>
  <header class="main_menu_sec navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
          <div class="lft_hd">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
          <div class="rgt_hd">
            <div class="main_menu">
              <nav id="nav_menu">
                <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>

                <div id="navbar">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#countsec">we</a></li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section id="slider_section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="slider">
          <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>


            <!--- wrapper -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

              <div class="item active">
                <div class="wrap_caption">
                  <div class="caption_carousel">
                    <h1>I see a Mountain at my gates </h1>
                    <p>I see more and more each day</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="item">
                <div class="wrap_caption">
                  <div class="caption_carousel">
                    <h1>What I give, it takes away</h1>
                    <p>Whether I go or when I stay</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="item">
                <div class="wrap_caption">
                  <div class="caption_carousel">
                    <h1>I see a mountain in my way</h1>
                    <p>It's looming larger by the day</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>

            <a class="left left_crousel_btn" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right right_crousel_btn" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>


          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <section id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12 ">
          <div class="title_sec">
            <h1>ABOUT</h1>
            <h2>Mountain at my gates</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12 ">
          <div class="abt centered">
            <p>I see it more and more each day What I give, it takes away Whether I go or when I stay </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="countsec">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

          <div class="count">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            <h2 class="counter">1994</h2>
            <h4>I see a Mountain at my gates</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="count">
            <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
            <h2 class="counter">21</h2>
            <h4>I see it more and more each day</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="count">
            <i class="fa fa-ticket"></i>
            <h2 class="counter">02</h2>
            <h4>It takes away </h4>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="count">
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
            <h2 class="counter">05</h2>
            <h4>My mountain</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

  <section id="serv">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12 ">
          <div class="title_sec">
            <h1>Mountain at my gates</h1>
            <h2>I see it more and more each day</h2>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="service centered">
            <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
            <h2>web Development</h2>
            <div class="service_hoverly">
              <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
              <h2>web Development</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ab odio quas , voluptate aspernatur!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="service centered">
            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
            <h2>E-mail marketing</h2>
            <div class="service_hoverly">
              <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
              <h2>E-mail marketing</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ab odio quas , voluptate aspernatur!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="service centered">
            <i class="fa fa-wordpress"></i>
            <h2>WordPress</h2>
            <div class="service_hoverly">
              <i class="fa fa-wordpress"></i>
              <h2>WordPress</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ab odio quas , voluptate aspernatur!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="service centered">
            <i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>
            <h2>Graphic Design</h2>
            <div class="service_hoverly">
              <i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>
              <h2>Graphic Design</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ab odio quas , voluptate aspernatur!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>

  <section id="team">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12 ">
          <div class="title_sec">
            <h1>Team</h1>
            <h2>Mountain</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12">
          <div class="all_team">

            <div class="sngl_team">
              <img src="http://wedesignthemes.com/themes/dt-mountcool/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/img-1.png" alt="" />
              <h3> Jamie Catllahan <span>Designer</span></h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecttur adipisicing elit. Laudant</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sngl_team">
              <img src="http://wedesignthemes.com/themes/dt-mountcool/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/img-2.png" alt="" />
              <h3>Lisa Kudrow <span> Manager </span></h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecttur adipisicing elit. Laudant</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sngl_team">
              <img src="http://wedesignthemes.com/themes/dt-mountcool/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/img-3.png" alt="" />
              <h3> John Clarance <span>   Senior Manager   </span></h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecttur adipisicing elit. Laudant</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
  </section>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/appear.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/showHide.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
  <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>

  <script>
    /*
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.counter').counterUp({
        delay: 10,
        time: 1000
      });
    });
    */
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 
    col-offset-*

in Bootstrap it will offset the column. So if you want a col-md-8 centered you would do something like:

```
<div class ="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"></div>
```

That should center you div. But you have to figure out based on the size of the div and size fo the viewport what the offset should be.

Note: it will offset the column on both sides this way.